# Help me identify these retro hubs

Tags: identify-this-bike, hub

I'm looking to get some NOS hubs to use with a screw-on singlespeed freewheel, the ones I'm using right now are far from perfect and I will not be able to rebuild them (the hub body itself is worn on the rear).

The seller says these are Ursus brand. Were these any good?

[image]

Comment: They look pretty generic to me.  The only odd thing is the brass-colored bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ursus is a real brand, even though you don't see a lot of them in the US. Most of their current stuff is fairly high-end, but the ones you're showing look pretty basic (and fairly old- by the 90's hubs were mostly cassettes, not freewheels). Should be fine for road riding/ commuting as long as you know how to lace a wheel. Otherwise the cost isn't going to be worth it and you should just get a pre-built wheel or wheelset.